# Why I don't see the list of directories in my FTP site in IIS?

Tags: ftp, iis

I created an FTP site. I set anonymous access to true, and I enabled anonymous authentication.

I checked it using Windows Explorer on my server and I could see the list of my directories using this addresses:

```
ftp://host:port/
ftp://ip:port/
```

However, I can't see the content of my FTP in FileZilla. And here is the log:

```
Status: Resolving address of DOMAIN
Status: Connecting to IP:PORT...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (...).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of DOMAIN
Status: Connecting to IP:PORT...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (...).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I'm stuck at this point. What is wrong?

I use Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.

**Update:** Here's FileZilla's log with Active Mode:

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of DOMAIN
Status: Connecting to IP:PORT...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PORT 62,102,140,42,195,248
Response:   200 PORT command successful.
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of DOMAIN
Status: Connecting to IP:PORT...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PORT 62,102,140,42,196,4
Response:   200 PORT command successful.
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

**Update 2**: I used Beyond Compare with Active Mode, and here's the log:

```
Stat> Connected.
Recv> 220 Microsoft FTP Service
Sent> USER anonymous
Recv> 331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
Sent> PASS ********
Recv> 230 User logged in.
Sent> FEAT
Recv> 211-Extended features supported:
Recv>  LANG EN*
       UTF8
Recv>  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
       PBSZ
       PROT C;P;
       CCC
Recv>  HOST
Recv>  SIZE
       MDTM
       REST STREAM
      211 END
Sent> OPTS UTF8 ON
Recv> 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Sent> TYPE A
Recv> 200 Type set to A.
Sent> SYST
Recv> 215 Windows_NT
Sent> TYPE A
Recv> 200 Type set to A.
Sent> PWD
Recv> 257 "/" is current directory.
Sent> REST 1
Recv> 350 Restarting at 1.
Sent> REST 0
Recv> 350 Restarting at 0.
Sent> PORT 192,168,1,158,23,116
Recv> 501 Server cannot accept argument.
Unable to load ftp://host:port/: Server cannot accept argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use FileZilla in passive mode, but your server might not support it or blocks port access with firewall. Since you can access your files using browser in active mode, then set FileZilla into active mode and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That didn't help. I tried an online FTP client (https://www.net2ftp.com/index.php) and it worked there. Something is not OK with my PC I guess.

Comment: Please post updated FileZilla log with active mode. There might be a clue about the problem.

Comment: The interesting point is that I used other online FTP clients and they won't connect, even in active mode. https://webftp.dreamhost.com/ didn't connect.

Comment: I can't force FileZilla to only use Active Mode. There is no configuration for it in Edit > Setitngs.

Comment: The problem may be that FTP is a really sucky protocol.  If your router is not good, or the Carrier Grade NAT your provider might be using is not good, it can break the protocol.   FTP requires 2 connections between the client and server (active vs passive mode determines if the second connection goes out from the client as well, or is made by the server).  Do you have a firewall running on your PC?  If so, what happens if you disable it and try to FTP?

Comment: Works perfectly in active mode. Does not work in passive. But the issue is that this is a remote computer, while I assume you are trying to login from local computer or network? I have no FileZilla installed at the moment, but internet suggests, that connection choice should be available at Settings -> FTP -> connection mode selection. Also there is a checkbox to fallback to alternative mode and you could turn it off during experiment.